# Probability of 1 at both end of string

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algorithms

Given a string S having N characters long and consists of only 1s and 0s.

Now given an integer K, let us pick two indexes i and j at random between 1 and N, both inclusive.

What's the probability that both S[i] and S[j] are 1 and |i−j|≤K ?

Example : Let N = 4  and K = 3

If string S = 1011 then here answer will be 9/16 as clearly out of 16 choices, 9 pairs of (i,j) satisfy our condition.

Comment: It depends on the string. So it needs to be given explicitly,  or generated by a specified random procedure.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I didn't get you

Comment: If you are asking for the probability for a **specific** string $S$, you must specify the string. For instance, the answer will be quite different if the string has lots of $1$'s than if it has few of them. If you do not specify the string, one can find a probability if we imagine the string is selected at random, say uniformly on the set of all strings of length $N$. But as things stand the problem is incompletely specified.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I dont want to have a formula ,But an algorithm to solve this very problem

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

Define $D=\left|i-j\right|$. Then $P\left\{ D=0\right\} =\frac{1}{N}$
and $P\left\{ D=d\right\} =\frac{2\left(N-d\right)}{N^{2}}$ for $d=1,\dots,N-1$.

So denoting the event by $E$ we find:

$P\left(E\right)=P\left(E|D=0\right)\frac{1}{N}+\sum_{d=1}^{N-1}P\left(E\mid D=d\right)\frac{2\left(N-d\right)}{N^{2}}$.

If $M$ denotes the number of $1$s in the string then $P\left(E\mid D=0\right)=\frac{M}{N}$.

Here it stops. To calculate the $P\left(E\mid D=d\right)$ for positive
$d$ you need more information about the string.

**addendum**:

Here $P(E\mid D=d)$ stands for the probability that event $E$ occurs under the extra condition that $D=d$.

Comment: If M denotes the number of 1s in the string then what about P(E∣D=d).?Please explain exactly what this notation means in your solution

Comment: For positive $d$ the conditional probability $P\left(E\mid D=d\right)$
is not completely determined by $M$.

Comment: I am asking what you mean by P(E∣D=d) exactly

Comment: See my addendum. If you are not yet familiar with conditional probabilities then my answer is not very useful for you.

Comment: And whats your Event here in your terms?

Comment: Exactly the event you describe in your question: both $S[i]$ and $S[j]$ are $1$ and $|i−j|\leq K$

Comment: Huh..so the question still stands.How to find this P(E∣D=d)

Comment: Yes. You can give a specific string and then ask the question. This leads to an answer (you did it yourself for $1011$) but when the string is not specified then it cannot be answered. Every string leads to different answers. E.g. if $K=3$ and $N=4$ then $1111$ gives probability $1$, but $0000$ gives probability $0$. This is my last comment on this. Good luck.

Comment: @drhab : the OP's questions are from various contests.